# android how to fill TextInput in another application

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection

We have to test application from other vendor(out client) and we need to fullfill text input from our android app(service) and get some info back.
Only way I see now - injects like `Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(motionEvent);`
But how to do it, if we working from our service to different real activity? Or maybe here is any more elegant solution to send text and push buttons in other app with rooted device as basement?

Comment: You should probably use some test framework like [Appium](http://appium.io/) or [Calabash-android](http://calaba.sh/)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html

Comment: So I can't do it on android, only with pc and emulator?